# Bluetooth Earbuds Issue on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I have a pair of earbuds that r not working with my ubuntu setup. The earbuds work fine on mobile devices (android/ios) and Windows machines. Ever since I shifted to Linux they stopped working. I tried all the solutions, reinstalled all the drivers but still no luck. Earbuds connect and then disconnect right after, they get deleted and then reinstalled, and repaired, and then disconnect again.

I tried pairing Samsung earbuds and they worked fine on this machine. But these earbuds which I m trying to connect are of a Chinese company. I checked all the different logs, the only thing I found unusual was:

tagged by udev as a keyboard. Even though the ID of these earbuds is of the headset, not the keyboard. Could anyone tell me which logs should I output here, and help me sort this matter out?

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Earbuds: Tronsmart Spunky Beats

Comment: I'm not an expert with this, but generally, you can't assume that "anything" will work with Linux.  You still need Linux-based drivers for it.  Sadly, some manufacturers only think of WIndows and Mac and don't consider compatibility with Linux.  The fact that your Samsung earbuds worked implies that your system might be working.  Anyway, perhaps someone else can give you better advice...  Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot. I was hoping maybe u know I could run windows drivers via an overlay on the Linux system. Just like WSL for windows.

Comment: Personally, I don't think that's a viable alternative to actually having Linux-based drivers.  As Linux isn't widely used (yet!), I'd stick with only popular brands (or those which show an interest in supporting Linux).  As for what you're hoping for, maybe someone else can help.  "WSL for Windows" is a Microsoft solution; I'm not sure how many people here can help you with that...

Comment: No you can not use windows drivers on any Linux distro. I also disagree that Linux is not widely used.